# Homepage meta title and description not showing in search engines?

Tags: title, seo, google-search

I have just launched a new website and have been having trouble locating it anywhere on search engines, so I decided to do a google search for ***"site:mysitename.com"*** to show all of the results from my website.

The homepage is the first page to be displayed, however, it is saying the meta title is a title of one of the blog posts on the website.

Once I click on the homepage link and view the source the meta title is set to ***Home | My Site Name*** as I have set it to. So my question is why in a search engine is the title of my homepage showing up as one of the blog posts names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't always show the meta descriptions and title's that you set. This is taken directly from Google's Search Console help pages.

> Google's generation of page titles and descriptions (or "snippets") is completely automated and takes into account both the content of a page as well as references to it that appear on the web. The goal of the snippet and title is to best represent and describe each result and explain how it relates to the user's query.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en